# Using the closure scope to keep the last value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
$('th').click(function() {
   var $th = $(this);
   ...
});
```

Using the closure scope, I want to say:

```
var $th;
$('th').click(function() {
   if ($th !== $(this)) {
      $th = $(this);
      ...
   }
});
```

Note: This code is just prior to </body>, so I won't need $(function() {});

Comment: I think I have to define this as an anonymous function that returns a function so that $th is defined before the return statement.

Comment: The reason that does not work, is that `$(this) != $(this)`, the jQuery constructor makes a new object, so you can not check it like that.  Otherwise the second statement would be fine.

Comment: Oh.  Maybe I should check $th.index() !== $(this).index()

Comment: See SLaks answer, that is the sensible method. (`$th[0]` is assuming you store `$th = $(this)`, presumably you are using `$th` further).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check whether the underlying DOM elements are equal:

```
if ($th[0] !== this) {
```

(You could also store `this` itself without calling `$`)