# Saving a variable in the closure scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
var Save = $('th:first')[0];

$('th').click(function() {
    if (Save !== this) {
        Save = this;
        ...
    }
});
```

How do I put "Save" into a closure scope?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the closure scope to keep the last value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240676/using-the-closure-scope-to-keep-the-last-value)

Comment: I know.  My original question had to do with closure, but you guys corrected me on another part of the code.

Comment: You would be better off editing your original question and deleting this one. Seeing that it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: Why do you want it in a closure? What are you trying to accomplish? (Not a criticism, just a query.)

Comment: The solution to my previous question had to do with using the right variable to do the comparison.  But my REAL question is: how to use the closure scope.

Comment: I think that closure is how you keep variables out of the global namespace.

Comment: Whilst this is not a duplicate, you could have added that to your original question, as it's in the exact same bit of code and is highly related.

Comment: I agree with Orbling, you could have just added to your previous question, something like : "And how do I protect the variable from the global scope?" This question was not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With jQuery, I tend to wrap the whole lot in a function, that passes in the `jQuery` object as `$`, to avoid namespace clashes on that shorthand, as [recommended by the jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Referencing_Magic_-_Shortcuts_for_jQuery).

```
(function($) {
    // ....
})(jQuery);
```

Any variables within that scope, for instance your `var Save`, are then out of the global name scope, in a closure.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really understand why you want to do what you're trying to do (or even what exactly you're trying to do...), but here are two solutions to what I think the question is about :

```
var Save = $('th:first')[0];

$('th').each(function() {
   var last = Save;
   $(this).click(function() {
      if (last !== this) {
         last = this;
          ...
      }
   });
});
```

and

```
var Save = $('th:first')[0];

$('th').data('Save', Save).click(function() {
    if ($(this).data('Save') !== this) {
        $(this).data('Save', this);
        ...
    }
});
```

** **EDIT** **

Of if what you want is just "shield" the variable `Save`, then

```
(function() {

var Save = $('th:first')[0];

$('th').click(function() {
    if (Save !== this) {
        Save = this;
        ...
    }
});

})();
```

Comment: If another function uses the variable "Save" in the global scope, just like this one, then I'm hosed.

Comment: This isn't what he is after, he is just trying to get his variable out of the global scope.  He could use `.data()`, but that would need to be on its own, not with the `var Save` or the problem still remains.

Comment: That's interesting to save the variable in the dom though...  That's another "scope" that I need to remember is available to me should I need it.

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn, the `.data()` JQuery function is to store data that is DOM related, which is required across scopes, and/or which should be discarded when the element is removed from the DOM tree, etc. In most cases, it is just faster and simpler to use what Orbling suggested.